# nginx reverse proxy multiple different backends

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a nginx reverse Proxy, which servers multiple external domains from outside. The nginx will pass requests on Port 80 as follows to the backends

> http://server1.domain.com   ---> http://backend1.domain.com
>
> http://server2.domain.com   ---> http://backend2.domain.com
>
> http://server3.domain.com   ---> http://backend3.domain.com

Now the strange behaviour. I have one conf file in sites-enabled. like test.conf. In this conf file only one backend with only one externe is configured like this:

```
server {
server_name server1.domain.com;
listen server1.domain.com:80;

 location ~ {
  proxy_pass_header Authorization;
  proxy_pass http://backend1.domain.com:80;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";
  proxy_buffering off;
  client_max_body_size 0;
  proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
  proxy_redirect off;
 }

 access_log /var/log/nginx/http_access.log;
 error_log  /var/log/nginx/http_error.log;

 }
```

So as you can see the config, only one backend is configured. BUT if I call http://server2.domain.com or http://server3.domain.com etc, it will still forward me to the CORRECT backend servers, even if I have configured just one?????. This seems to me very very strange.

on the other hand I can proxy with the stream ssl_preload module on port 443 or any other port just fine. So when I remove one of the servers from the map directive, it will not route to the backend. This situation is just OK. My main concern is the Port 80 acting so strange, why???!!??

Comment: Are all the services at the same IP address?

Comment: All backends have different IP's. So from external, people just call the different domain names. on the external DNS the different domain names point to the SAME reverse proxy IP. The reverse proxy receives the requests based on the different domain names and forwards them to the correct backends. The idea is to only expose one public IP, but serving different backends. The 443 forward works just fine. Only the http/80 traffic is acting very weird. The rewrite of Port 80 to Port 443 is done on the backends, not on the reverse proxy to avoid extra troubleshoot. The rp is just proxing. thx

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to test the configuration and view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading across all files.

Comment: Well in the sites-enabled only one web server is configured to proxy_pass with one IP to the backend on Port 80, but I can still call the other webservers, which are not configured on Port 80. Do you want me to send you the nginx -T output?

Comment: Well I try to ask a little different, how does the ssl_preread/ ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module handle Port 80 requests? I mean I do not have any conf files for Port 80 in sites-enabled, but the port 80 requests are still forwarded to the backends, which are rewriting them to 443. so all the magic is done on the  ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module module. But how??? How does it work with TCP http 80 Port?? I'm really confused. I just need to understand this behaviour. thx